# Annotating Spring view class

Tags: java, spring, view, annotations

I have a class extending the AbstractExcelView class of Spring which renders an XML file.  Within this class, I am injecting my Service bean for use.  I am autowiring and component scanning my classes, and I would like to also do the same with this view class, but I am not clear how (or if it can be done).  Here's what I'm trying to annotate from the config:

```
<bean id="export.xls" class="com.my.views.ReportExcelView">
<property name="url">
    <value>/excel/template</value>
</property>
<property name="service" ref="testingService"/>
```

I am able to annotate the class with @Component, and the service with @Autowired, but I don't know of a strategy to annotate the URL.  What I'd really like to do is condition it within the buildExcelWorkbook() call (based on something in the request), but it seems there is some initialization done before this, as I get an error trying to use my excel template with this method that indicates it does not have a handle to the Excel sheet.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your ReportExcelView probably looks like this right now.  Make sure you use @Resource to wire a simple String.

```
package com.ex.springbasicex.view;
@Component
public class ReportExcelView{
    @Resource(name="myUrl")
    String url;

    @Autowired
    Service service;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Your context config probably should be like what is below using scanning.  Below is how to set the myUrl String resource.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ex.springbasicex.view"  />
<bean id="myUrl" class="java.lang.String" >
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>/excel/template</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Since the string url is actually on the base class, I just annotated the setUrl with @Resource and it worked.